# PHP object method doesn't behave as I expect

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I can't quite understand why the output of this code is  '1'.
My guess is that php is not behaving like most other OO languages that I'm used to, in that the arrays that php uses must not be objects. Changing the array that is returned by the class does not change the array within the class. How would I get the class to return an array which I can edit (and has the same address as the one within the class)?

```
<?php
    class Test
    {
        public $arr;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->arr = array();
        }

        public function addToArr($i)
        {
            $this->arr[] = $i;
        }

        public function getArr()
        {
            return $this->arr;
        }
    }

    $t = new Test();
    $data = 5;
    $t->addToArr($data);

    $tobj_arr = $t->getArr();
    unset($tobj_arr[0]);

    $tobj_arr_fresh = $t->getArr();
    echo count($tobj_arr_fresh);
?>
```

EDIT: I expected the output to be 0

Comment: A static class/variable would get the job done.

Comment: If you expect it to return 0, you're probably testing the wrong variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return the array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). That way, php returns a reference to the array, in stead of a copy.

```
<?php
    class Test
    {
        public $arr;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->arr = array();
        }

        public function addToArr($i)
        {
            $this->arr[] = $i;
        }

        public function & getArr() //Returning by reference here
        {
            return $this->arr;
        }
    }

    $t = new Test();
    $data = 5;
    $t->addToArr($data);

    $tobj_arr = &$t->getArr(); //Reference binding here
    unset($tobj_arr[0]);

    $tobj_arr_fresh = $t->getArr();
    echo count($tobj_arr_fresh);
?>
```

This returns 0.

From the [returning references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) subpage:

> Unlike parameter passing, here you have to use & in both places - to
>   indicate that you want to return by reference, not a copy, and to
>   indicate that reference binding, rather than usual assignment, should
>   be done

Note that although this gets the job done, question is if it is a good practice. By changing class members outside of the class itself, it can become very difficult to track the application.

Comment: +1  My only comment is that I think that your caveat question if ... is probably too mild ;-?  The idea of a getXXX() method enabling you to write to object properties -- Yukkk!

Answer (score 2):

Because array are passed by "copy on write" by default, getArr() should return by reference:

```
    public function &getArr()
    {
        return $this->arr;
    }

[snip]

$tobj_arr = &$t->getArr();
```

For arrays that are object, use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/arrayobject). Extending ArrayObject is probably better in your case.

Answer (score 2):

When you `unset($tobj_arr[0]);` you are passing the *return value* of the function call, and not the actual property of the object.

When you call the function again, you get a fresh copy of the object's property which has yet to be modified since you added 5 to it.

Since the property itself is public, try changing:
`unset($tobj_arr[0]);`

To: `unset($t->arr[0]);`

And see if that gives you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting "1" because you are asking PHP how many elements are in the array by using count. Remove count and use print_r($tobj_arr_fresh)